# Hide ngx-bootstrap popover on mobile device?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I like the ngx-bootstrap popovers, but when using them on a mobile device they open on tap and stay there until you tap elsewhere.
This is not very good behaviour on the small screen.

Any suggestions on how to easily disable popovers on mobile devices?
Or ideas for something else that works better on all size devices?